# Layout grid with images, labels, scrollview

Tags: ios, layout, grid, uiimage

I'm creating a layout for an iPad app that will consist of xx number of images and buttons(dynamically determined based on response from web service call) and I need to place them in a grid-like layout in a scroll view(horizontal)...
Now, I know that there are many custom UI Controls that can do something similar to this, but I haven't found one to match my 'needs'...

Basically what I want/need is that each 'entry' has an image, an overlay image, a button matching the size of the image and two labels on top of the image...

So does anybody know of a custom UI control that would match what I want?

Or do I have to write this from scratch?

I can potentially have as little as 10 entries, but also all the way up to 100+ (probably not a lot higher than this), so perhaps there is a more memory-friendly approach then what I'm considering below... - another issue is that I need to redo this every time the view appears(reason: I need to show updated data)...

I've done some initial testing of creating the grid manually, and have this so far:

```
int rows = 3; // fixed, will either be 2 or 3, depending on final size of images...
int columns = 8;// will be determined by response from web service

for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        // Create the buttons to handle button press
        UIButton *childButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        childButton.frame = CGRectMake(i * 100 + 10, j * 100 + 20, 100, 30);

        [childButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [childButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentPopoverMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:childButton];

        // Create the images to display the pictures of the children


        // Create the labels to display child name


        // Create the labels to display pick up time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating custom view... Create a custom class from UIView and put all those controls on it. You should probably create initWithCustomData where custom data is what you get from web. Once you have all that you can sort them anyway you want as if they were a single simple control.
As for updating. If the whole view has fixed size just create some inner methods in custom view to change frames of subviews. If frame is dynamic you basically do the same but you have to reposition all custom views (just use UIView animations).